# Suppose $\sum a_n c^n$ converges for some nonzero real number c. Then $\sum a_n x^n $ converges absolutely for all x such that |x| < |c|.

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\sum a_n c^n$ converges for some nonzero real number c. Then $\sum a_n x^n $ converges absolutely for all x such that |x| < |c|.

could you please help me how can I use nth term test and comparison test to prove it ?

Comment: $|a_n x^n| = |a_n c^n| |(\frac{x}{c})^n|$

Comment: Most of the basic series proofs (including this one) use the method: "compare to a geometric series".

Answer (score 2):

From the fact $\sum a_nc^n$ converges we can conclude $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_nc^n = 0$$
Now we can look at $$q = \frac{|x|}{|c|} \lt 1$$
And rewrite
$$|a_nx^n| = |a_nc^n||q^n| \le q^n\sup_p\{|a_px^p|\}$$
And we know $\sup_n\{|a_nx^n|\}\in\mathbb{R}$ because $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_nc^n = 0$, from here we an use the comparison test with the geometric sequence.

Comment: how can I use comparison test with the geometric sequence., I did search on internet but I did not find anything about that?thank you

Comment: @rianasd If you know $a_n \ge b_n \ge 0 \ \forall n$, and also $\sum a_n$ converges, what can you say about $\sum b_n$?

Comment: it will be converges too

Comment: but how can I use that when I have sup ?

Comment: how can I show that the series of q^n sup is converges?

Comment: @rianasd $\sup_n\{|a_nx^n|\}$ is merely some finite number is this case, and it can be concluded that it's a finite number from the reasons provided in the answer.

Comment: how about the series of q^n  is converges?